# Submitting input type="image" to another servlet failed to return any parameters

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

servlet1:

I'm trying to pass parameters to another servlet2:

..

```
out.print("<input type='text' name='someText' src='someSrc' onclick='submit()'/>");
```

..

clicked it - servlet2 is loading.

servlet2:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();                
        Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
        while (params.hasMoreElements())
        {
            out.print("parameter: " + (String)params.nextElement() + "</br>");
        }
}
```

my output --> someText
so far so good!

but when my input type is image my output is empty:

```
out.print("<input type='image' name='someText' src='someSrc' onclick='submit()'/>");
```

any suggestions?

Comment: please show the function submit()

Comment: how exactly the values are getting transferred ? to send an image, i think you should use multi part request. isnt it ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML specification, the `input type="image"` is to be used as an image map. The web browser will send the x and y position of the mouse pointer to the server when the end user clicks on the image map.

```
out.print("<input type=\'image\' name=\'imgButton\' src=\'flowsheet/images/submit_button.gif\'/>");
```

The submitted value will be available as `imgButton.x` and `imgButton.y`

But,If you just want to use styled button in your page to submit data. Use `input type="submit"` where you can specify CSS background image for button.